# Flow js doesn`t apply generic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, flowtype

I have a function (react hook):

```
function useHandles<TPreparedValues, TValues>({
    onReject,
    makeData,
}: ArgsType<TPreparedValues, TValues>) {
    const handleLeavePage =  (formData: TValues) => onReject(makeData(formData))

    return {
      handleLeavePage
    }
}
```

Where ArgsType is:

```
type ArgsType<TPreparedValues, TValues> = {
    onReject: (TPreparedValues) => Promise<void>,
    makeData: TValues => TPreparedValues
};
```

Then I use this hook:

```
const {
    handleLeavePage,
} = useDocumentHandles<DocumentEditInputType, ValuesType>({
    onReject,
    makeData,
})
```

As you see I define that **TValues = ValuesType**. Of course, flowjs should guess it from **onReject** typing.

But when I use **handleLeavePage**, I get an error: 
*`TValues` [1] is incompatible with  `ValuesType` [2] in the first argument of property `onLeavePage`.*

I think flowjs doesn't understand that TValue is generic in **handleLeavePage** .

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4BVwQDwoApwmAQzwBMA1AgGwFcIkAaKFc62gPigF4oBvAKCgFQA9gDsAShABWEAMbAAXFAAUOPIRLMaSAJSd2uIQFsAlkkwA3IceKs6-QYYIBrCABECwAoqaUtexrj4RBBkvrS8AL4A3Ly8AGZUInLGolBUZgASBCLEFLRYgeohmrSK3BEMPixIZRGsSnyCwuJSssB2TY4u7p52EYrwyGiQBWrBodWVJUis2mUAPlAAFtm5EAAyEATmENgECBCKKtO6HPpwRqYWVjZQ8xE89gIyokjAy6t5m9u7+9BcSjiQjghh6BFO7FEEmkciUXTcHgIgOBoMR2m0sSaeGAVDgIkeTQEKxyXy2Oz2ByeUAikVioEgUFcQhkVEMEBEwAAosRjMAAJIiMBUYDDf48RYAD0UIlZACMIHA7tFePToNNRZxxVAQIo3nBjCIEEqYrxiLIKMEoOYiM1oW0jkyWWyOdzeQKhSL0BCoAYTGYMJZrKwYmaZBa8FabfCwYp1eh-I7WeyuTz+YLhaKTS8RG8CYJiWtvuS-n1NekIFkSbQGlSoa05B0HM4Eb1ItoTQXST8KRAGtrFAByAfU9tAA)

Instead of declaring type of the `handleLeavePage` argument, type the output of the `useHandles` function.

Comment: Thank you! Typing the output of the useHandlers helps me